# Split file in linux to different chunks

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I need to split a file to several parts.

Original file:

```
Header 1
 text 1.1
 text 1.2
Header 2
 text 2.1
 text 2.2
```

So, i need to split this to:

stream1.chunk:

```
Header 1
 text 1.1
 text 1.2
```

stream2.chunk:

```
Header 2
 text 2.1
 text 2.2
```

ps header must be a part of the chunk.

I have tried to solve the problem with regex "look around" feature, but without success.

Comment: Please take a look at [how to format my code block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Please edit your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 2):

With any [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk '/^Header/{c=$2} {print > ("stream"c".chunk"); close("stream"c".chunk")}' file
ls stream*chunk
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how can i get split files with HeaderXXX in their names?

Comment: `print > "stream"c".chunk"` is undefined behavior, it'd need to be `print > ("stream"c".chunk")` to work in all awks. POSIX requires parens around any expression on  the right side of input or output redirection.

Comment: Thanks Ed, post edited accordingly

Answer (score 2):

You could use "csplit"

```bash
csplit original_file '/^Header/' '{*}' --prefix=chunk_ --suffix-format='%02d.txt' --elide-empty-files
```

I think it's installed by default in most debian based distributions. Just in case you cant found it. Install it with:

```bash
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install coreutils
```

Comment: Thank you, i have already tried with csplit, but i want to rename my chunks into Header prefix from the original file. File names must be look like Header1.chunk Header2.chunk